# introduction to algorithms CLRS insertion sort nonincreasing

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am currently on the second chapter of Introduction to algorithms by CLRS, and I've come across a strange exercise. It asks me to sort the insertion sort so that is nonincreasing instead of nondecreasing.

So I presume that for a given array A = { 91, 23, 24 ,54, 23} this would turn out as this { 23, 23, 24, 54, 91} for nondecreasing.

However, if it is nonincreasing does that mean it would turn out like this? { 91, 54, 24, 23, 23}? I searched around on the internet and am asking this out of curiosity and for clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is sorted in non-increasing order if every element (starting from the second one) is less than or equal to the previous one.

So the array `{91, 23, 24 ,54, 23}` sorted in non-increasing order is indeed `{91, 54, 24, 23, 23}`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136657/algorithm-clrs-solution-more-in-depth-discussion-need

Comment: I was looking for a short answer, not a discussion. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

yes, nonincreasing array is an order that doesn't increase, but it may or may not decrease (Just not increase).

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead